# numpy condition loop np.where

Tags: python, loops, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to compare a sample column to two reference columns, D and R. If sample matches D or R it replaces that data with D or R; unless ./. is in the sample column then I want the call to be NR. I have added the LogicCALL column to demonstrate-- in my actual data dataframe those calls would replace (1,0, ./.)

```
  ReferenceD ReferenceR sample LogicCALL
0          1          0      1         D
1          1          1    ./.        NC
2          1          0      0         R
Index(['ReferenceD', 'ReferenceR', 'sample', 'LogicCALL'], dtype='object')
```

To this point I have construct the loop below; where Alt is a list of samples. The loop works for calling D and R's but not NC's, instead the script returns "R".

```
for sample in Alt:
      gtdata[(sample)] = np.where((gtdata[(sample)] == gtdata['ReferenceD']) & (gtdata[sample] != gtdata['ReferenceR']), "D",
                                 np.where((gtdata[(sample)] == "D") & (gtdata[(sample)] is not ('\./.')), "D",
                                           np.where((gtdata[(sample)] == "D") & (gtdata[(sample)].str.contains('\./.')), "NC",
                                                   "R")))
```

Comment: I don't see a loop.  I see nested or sequential `where`.  It's hard to tell which.  I'd have to copy it to an editor and break it into readable pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a functional syntax but the most readable way to do this would be to procedurally make the assignemnts:

```
df.loc[df['ReferenceD'].astype(str) == df['sample'], 'LogicCALL'] = 'D'
df.loc[df['ReferenceR'].astype(str) == df['sample'], 'LogicCALL'] = 'R'
df.loc[df['sample'] == './.',                        'LogicCALL'] = 'NR'
```